# Noetherian quotient ring of non-noetherian non-commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request, noetherian

Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring which is not noetherian. Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. What are some conditions on $I$ such that the quotient *ring* $R/I$ is noetherian?
Does this happen for example if $I$ is principal, or even just finitely generated?

Don't even know where to start to be honest, so this may also be treated as a reference request.

Comment: $I$ being principal is definitely not enough. Let $S$ be a non noetherian ring, put $R=S\times\mathbb{Z}$ and let $I=\left\langle (0,1)\right\rangle$. Then $R/I\simeq S$ is not noetherian, but $I$ is principal.

Comment: @Andijvie: Nice simple example, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is stolen from one of the exercise of Atiyah & Macdonald "Introduction to commutative algebra" (Chapter 6, Exercise 4). I assume that $R$ is commutative however (but maybe this assumption can be dropped).

Let $M$ be a noetherian module. Then take $I=(0:M)=\{a\in R: aM=0\}$. Then $R/I$ is noetherian. Conversely suppose that $R/I$ is noetherian. Then it is noetherian as an $R$-module (the $R$-action on $R/I$ is the same as the $R/I$-action) and $(0:R/I)=I$.

In total we get the characterization: $R/I$ is noetherian iff $I$ is the anhilitator of a noetherian $R$-module.

A proof of $\Leftarrow$ goes as follows: as $M$ is noetherian it is finitely generated by $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in M$, say. Consider the map
$$ \phi:R \to \bigoplus_{i=1}^n M, \quad a\mapsto (ax_1,\ldots,ax_n).$$ By definition $\ker \phi = (0:M)$. Thus $\phi$ induces an injection $R/(0:M)\hookrightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^n M$ and the module on the right is noetherian, so $R/(0:M)$ is noetherian as it identifies with a submodule of a noetherian module.

Comment: Thanks for this. Some issues I have (beside the commutativity): I would prefer if the codomain of $\phi$ was written as $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M$, as it is less confusing. Also, this only shows that $R/(0:M)$ is a noetherian $R$-module.

Comment: The following should work: Let $I \leq R$ be an ideal in a noetherian ring. Ideals of $R/I$ are of the form $J/I$ with $I \leq J \leq R$. Since $R$ is noetherian, $J$ is finitely generated. Thus $J/I$ is finitely generated, and hence $R/I$ is noetherian.

Comment: We also have that for some ideal $I$ of $R$ the $R$-submodules of $R/I$ are the same as the $R/I$-submodules of $R/I$. So $R/I$ is a northerian ring iff it is a northerian $R$-module. And I have implemented your notational critique.